# TableView not reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am designing a one-to-one chatting interface using table view. This table view is modified to show bubbles as some new message arrives. The new message arrives through a push-notification in this case. I call following code in my function which receives message through the push notification:

```
-(void)messageReceived: (NSString *)message{
    _message=[message retain];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

However, it seems this does not reload my table view. 
If I place the call for `reloadData` in the `viewDidAppear` function, it reloads fine. It also reloads fine, if I place the `reloadData` call in a function whose return type is `IBAction` (ex: a function binding to button click)

What could be the reason for `reloadData` to not get triggered through custom declared functions ?

Comment: how do you call the messageReceived through push notification?

Comment: @verbumdei i am calling this method from my appDelegate.m file, where i am handling the inbound notification in this delegate: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I extract the the message from "alert" tag under "aps" tag of the received notification(just like a JSON) and pass it to the messageReceived function.

Comment: and what is your data source for the table view? Can you post your code for the table view data source methods, such as `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Answer (score 2):

reloaddata method is called but the trick here that you didn't add the incoming message to the datasource that the tableview load from !

Answer (score 1):

may be you have not Connect the Tableview with table view Delegates and Datasource

Objective-C

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>

yourtableview.delegate = self;
yourtableview.dataSource = self;

[tableView reloadData];
```

Swift 3

```
class YourClass: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
yourtableview.delegate = self
yourtableview.dataSource = self

yourtableview.reloadData()
```

the other way is! for Swift and Objective-C both.
Right Click on the Table view and drag and drop the delegates.

[image]