# Swift TableView cell doesnt show

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have the problem that my TableViewController doesn't show the content of the cell(s). I have a button that loads the data which works but should also be shown in the cells. Did I forget something in the "vieDidLoad" function? You can find images from the Storyboard and the app at the end.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    //btn.setTitle("Add new Dummy", for: UIControlState)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addDummyData), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btn)
}
@objc func addDummyData() {
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRandomCar { (json: NSArray?) in

        if let results = json {
            for entry in results {
                self.items.append(CarObject(json: entry as! Dictionary))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    }
    let car = self.items[indexPath.row]
    print(car.pictureURL)
    if let url = NSURL(string: car.pictureURL) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            cell.carImage?.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        }
    }

    // Create Swift / Cocoa Touch file with carImage etc. Actionbutton
    cell.carTitleLabel.text = "test"//car1
    cell.carPriceLabel.text = car.carPrice
    print("test3")
    return cell
}
```

}

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA4OO.png)

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPmPE.png)

Comment: Have you added numberOfRowsInSection delegate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TableView not reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681525/tableview-not-reloading)

Comment: I tried these: func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

Comment: I am using a UITableViewController so it says that declaring datasource and delegate is redundant. I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Like Rishabh said, you need to set datasource and delegate in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.datasource = self
   tableView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put in this line "class TableViewController: UITableViewController" in the code snippet. So this becomes redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set DataSource and Delegate in your viewDiDLoad()
Something like below.

```
 self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have these functions for a default `UITableViewController`. Maybe you missed one of them.

```
import UIKit

class YourViewController: UITableViewController {

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1 //Your section count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count //Your row count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
    }
    let car = self.items[indexPath.row]
    print(car.pictureURL)
    if let url = NSURL(string: car.pictureURL) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            cell.carImage?.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        }
    }

    // Create Swift / Cocoa Touch file with carImage etc. Actionbutton
    cell.carTitleLabel.text = "test"//car1
    cell.carPriceLabel.text = car.carPrice
    print("test3")
    return cell
}

}
```

Note: You should also check your `self.items.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Your `return` value should not be 0.

Comment: Thanks I just tried this. It might have been solved but I'm receiving another error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/flowinger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/01CA5F70-F8B5-48B6-8352-1B2236F78C49/data/Containers/Bundle/...> (loaded)' with name 'TableViewCell''

Comment: Did you set your TableViewCell's identifier in storyboard?

Comment: You should open your Storyboard, select your TableViewCell, open Attributes Inspector in right menu, find Table View Cell section and add "TableViewCell" in Identifier text field.

Comment: It can be occur if you renamed your xib or storyboard file outside the xcode. You can see possible fixing ways in these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842740/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle 
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722461/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbun